# Unable to connect my asp.net mvc web application to the sql server after deploying it to IIS7

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis-7

I have an asp.net mvc web application, and it used to connect well to the sql server when running it from Visual studio (on debug mode) . but after i have deployed it to IIS 7 using windows authntication, i am getting the following error:-

```
 Login failed for user '<ourDomainName>\<ourServerName>$'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '<ourDomainName>\<ourServerName>$'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Can anyone adive , what is causing this error ?

Thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the app pool identity.It looks like you're using integrated authentication, if that's the case the app pool user need to have the appropriate permissions in the Sql Server.

Comment: yes i have created the application pool , and my user name do have the required permission on the SQL server. so not sure what is wrong ?

Comment: So what is the identity assigned to the application pool in the advanced settings? Is it a built in account (like Network Service,Local System etc.) or some custom account.

Comment: and i have tried to chnage the identity for the application pool. by going to >> IIS >> application pool>> select the required application pool>> advance setting>> identity, i select custom account, then i typed my username and password. but i got the following error , ""The Specific password is invalid" although i typed a complex password something such as "sW@ssw0rd" . can you advice what might be the problem ?

Comment: the select identity is for the built-in account is "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

Comment: if you're using a domain account you should include the domain name with the username.

Comment: i already did that when i try to define a custom account. but i got the following error "The Specific password is invalid" !!